# Navigating to Blacklisted URL's and Canceling Them

Tags: javascript, browser, firefox-addon, message, content-script

I need to write a Firefox extension that creates a blacklist and whitelist of URL's, and checks to make sure the user wants to navigate to them whenever the user attempts to do so.  I'm doing this using a main script and a content script that I attach to every page (using PageMod); I attached a listener using jQuery to every link (with the tag "a") which executes a function using window.onbeforeunload.  I have two questions:

1. How would I prompt/ask the user if they actually did want to go to the site?
2. How would I stop the browser from navigating to the site if the user decided not to?

Right now my code passes messages between the two scripts in order to accomplish my goal; as far as I can tell, I can only use "document" in the content script, and save the blacklist/whitelist in the main script.  I'm using simple-storage to save my lists, and the port module to pass messages between the scripts.

For question 1, I've attempted using confirm(message) to get a positive/negative response from the user, but the popup either doesn't show up or shows up for a split second then gets automatically answered with a negative response.  When I look in my console's error messages, I see a "prompt aborted by user" error.

For question 2, I've already tried using event.preventDefault() by passing the click event to the function (this worked, I think).  Is there a better way to do this?  I've seen people using window.location = "", et cetera to do this.

Anyways, the code is below:

**MAIN.JS**

```
var ss = require("sdk/simple-storage");

exports.main = function() {
  if (!ss.storage.blacklist) {
    ss.storage.blacklist = [];}
  if (!ss.storage.whitelist) {
    ss.storage.whitelist = [];}
  var data = require("sdk/self").data;
  var pageMod = require("sdk/page-mod");
    pageMod.PageMod({
      include: "*",          
      contentScriptFile: [data.url("jquery-1.10.2.min.js"),data.url("secChk.js")],
      onAttach: function(worker) {

        function whiteCNTD(str) {
          for (var index = 0; index < ss.storage.whitelist.length; index++) {
            if (ss.storage.whitelist[index] == str) {
              return index;
            }
          } 
          return -1;
        }

        function blackCNTD(str) {
          for (var index = 0; index < ss.storage.blacklist.length; index++) {
            if (ss.storage.blacklist[index] == str) {
              return index;
            }
          } 
          return -1;
        }

        function checkLists(URL) {
          if (whiteCNTD(URL) == -1) {
            if (blackCNTD(URL) != -1) {
              var bool = false;
              worker.port.emit("navq", "Do you want to go to this link and add it to the whitelist?");
              worker.port.on("yes", function() {
                bool = true;
              });
              worker.port.on("no", function() {
                bool = false;
              });
            if (bool == true) {
              ss.storage.blacklist.splice(index, 1);
              ss.storage.whitelist.push(URL);
              return true;
            }
            else {
              return false;
            }
          }
          else {
            var bool = false;
            worker.port.emit("safeq", "Is this a safe site?");
            worker.port.on("yes", function() {
              bool = true;
            });
            worker.port.on("no", function() {
              bool = false;
            });
            if (bool == true) {
              ss.storage.whitelist.push(URL);
              return true;
            }
          else {
            ss.storage.blacklist.push(URL);
            return false;
          }
        }
      }
      return true;
    }

    worker.port.on("newURL", function(URL) {
      var s = "";
      s = URL;
      if (checkLists(s)) {
        worker.port.emit("good", s);
      } else if (!checkLists(s)) {
        worker.port.emit("bad", s);
        }
      });
    }
  });
}
```

**SECCHK.JS**

```
//Check if the site is a bad site whenever a link is clicked
$("a").click(function(event) {
  window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    self.port.on("navq", function(message) {
      var r = confirm("Do you want to go to this link and add it to the whitelist?");
      if (r == true) {
        self.port.emit("yes", message);
      } else if (r == false) {
        self.port.emit("no", message);
      }
    });
    self.port.on("safeq", function(message) {
      var r = confirm("Is this a safe site?");
      if (r == true) {
        self.port.emit("yes", temp);
      } else if (r == false) {
        self.port.emit("no", temp);
      }
    });
    link = document.activeElement.href;
    self.port.emit("newURL", link);
    self.port.on("good", function(message) {
      return true;
    });
    self.port.on("bad", function(message) {
      return false;
    });
  }   
});
```